# Can anyone suggest a reading list for perspectives on aesthetics, specifically two dimensional visual art?

Tags: free-will, aesthetics

Can anyone suggest a reading list for perspectives on aesthetics, particularly visual art? I am interested in the critical interpretation of specifically two dimensional drawing and painting through emotion, psychology perspectivism. Is the will to power the driving force for creativity?

Answer (score 0):

You might find some useful reading and resources in the SEP article for [creativity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/creativity/), and the IEP article for [Art and Interpretation](https://iep.utm.edu/art-and-interpretation/) should help and is most specific to your question. I'll list some other works on aesthetics that you might be interested in, but are more unrelated to your question.

I would look at sections of Plato's Republic (Books 3 and 10 iirc) where he talks about art as being an imitation. [Here is the SEP article on his philosophy of aesthetics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-aesthetics/). There are some implications about what they might mean about the interpretation of art but it isn't discussed here.

Because you mentioned Nietzsche you might want to read The Birth of Tragedy as well. It's one of his first works and it's pretty unrefined, focuses on dramatic theory rather than visual art, and doesn't mention the will to power, but it might interest you if you're a fan of his work.